# Better / Inline way to persist a variable between each iteration of Array.map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsx

I have an array in which some elements are implicitly paired with other elements, but not necessarily adjacent. I use `Array.map` over this array to create JSX elements (not important) but I need to keep track between each iteration of if I've already seen an elements pair.

The code is effectively as such:

```
let pairedElementsSeen= {};
return <...>
    {myArray.map(elem => {
        if (elem.pairKey in pairedElementsSeen) {
            return secondaryOption;
        }
        else {
            pairedElementsSeen[elem.key] = someValue;
            return defaultOption;
        }
    )}
</...>;
```

This already works as is, but I don't like that I need the extra `pairedElementsSeen` object which, because of the structure and length of the JSX, must be defined well in advance of where it is used. Is there some way with `Array.map` or else a similar function to be able to carry a variable like `pairedElementsSeen` between each iteration?

The only things I can think of would either be to

1. Extract this whole section into a dedicated for loop before all of
   the JSX, which I don't like because it displaces the behavior from
   the place where it is used, or
2. Create a one-off, instantly called arrow function with the persistent
   object defined within. I find these to be particularly un-intuitive when reading however and plus it will lose it's abilitiy to be combined inline with other array operations like `sort` or `filter`.

That would look like this ugly mess:

```
return <...>
    {(() => {
        let pairedElementsSeen = {};
        return myArray.map(...);
    })()}
</...>;
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it without the intermediate object (but less efficiently) like this:

```js
return <...>
    {myArray.map((elem, i, arr) => {
        const pairedElementSeen = arr.findIndex(e => e.key === elem.pairKey) < i;
        return pairedElementSeen ? secondaryOption : defaultOption;
    })}
</...>;
```

O(n) way to do it (uses intermediate object but all in one array function call):

```js
return <...>
    {myArray.reduce((agg, elem) => {
      if (elem.pairKey in agg.pairedElementsSeen) {
        agg.results.push(secondaryOption);
      } else {
        agg.pairedElementsSeen[elem.key] = true;
        agg.results.push(defaultOption);
      }

      return agg;
    }, { pairedElementsSeen: {}, results: [] }).results}
</...>;
```

Comment: I had thought of this solution, but hadn't really considered it since its O(n^2). I assume that's the only way to do it without the intermediate object though, so thanks.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) but I can only think of kinda ugly ways to do it. I'll edit with one of those anyway.

Comment: Added O(n) option

Comment: (I mispoke it does use an intermediate object but all in one array function call)

Comment: The `reduce` seems to be the closest to what I had in mind when asking the question. Unfortunate there isn't an even more elegant way to do it, but you can't win them all.